# Execute dsl formated script within a python script in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline job

Sample code:

```
stage (job1){
    sh "generate_dsl.py"
    // Output of python script is dsl script - runbuild.groovy 
    load runbuild.groovy
}
```

- python script 'generate_dsl.py' has a logic based on the inputs, to dynamically create a dsl format groovy script  called runbuild.groovy'
- Next it will load runbuild.groovy and stages.
  Stage view of the job will display all these stages present in the runbuild.groovy

Sample runbuild.groovy (does not have a fixed stages/steps):

```
stages ('build'){
    stage('setup'){
        node('ubuntu'){
            sh "setup_script.sh"
        }
    }
    parallel(
        stage1....
        stage2 ...
    )
}
```

Is there a way to execute runbuild.groovy, inside python script "generate_dsl.py"

Our build consists of python and shell scripts. We are using Jenkins mainly for scheduling.

how we can utilize the full power of jenkins in our CI/CD that has lots of python and shell scripts to run?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The DSL tells Jenkins things which it will not be able to know if you hide it.

Comment: I am not hiding
- Run the python script to generate DSL script on the fly
- Come back to stage block , load runbuild.groovy file.
- Then run next python modules.

Instead , can we load the DSL groovy file from the python script ?
Whatever I am currently doing - is it fine or is there any better way to handle ?